# Android: Key Stroke Count

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Im trying to record the number of keystrokes in an edittext in my android app, but im coming up blank with a way to do it.

Im thinking that a TextWatcher is the way to achieve this, but nothing is working at the moment. Im a novice android developer, so any help much appreciated.

```
 mainTextBlock.addTextChangedListener(keyCounter);
    ...
    TextWatcher keyCounter = new TextWatcher() {

  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
   keyCount++;
   TextView keystrokeCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.keystrokeCount);
   keystrokeCount.setText(keyCount);
  }

  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
    int after) {   
  }

  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
    int count) {
  }

    };
```

Im getting a force close every time I enter any text into the main text block. Im trying to count the keystrokes, not the number of characters within the edittext, otherwise it would be fairly straight forward...

Many thanks!

Comment: Please post the error from logcat

Comment: Also you should bear in mind that people who use things like swype might not make any keystrokes that you can count.

Comment: @dave.c Are you sure? `TextWatcher` should listen for text change events and not for keyboard press events

Comment: Dave- thats actually the reason im doing this, its for a dissertation on soft keyboard input mehtods

Comment: Is this what you wanted from logcat? 01-31 23:01:47.976: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
Apologies for my lack of knowledge of android development!

Comment: @Francesco when I use swype, no text is entered into the text box until I have finished swyping the word.  Then the whole word is entered in one go.  As such it could well be pasting the entire word in at once, rather than one character at a time.  The text change would still be registered, but you wouldn't necessarily get every "keypress".

Comment: @Dave.c For the purposes of my dissertation, that is actually helpful, as that would be 1 keystroke per word- one of the measures in comparing input methods

Answer (score 1):

> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:
>   String resource ID #0x1

This means that you are trying to reference a resource that doesn't exist.  I don't see anything in the code snippet that looks like it would be the problem, but right after that logcat snippet should be another line that includes a file and line number.  This should point you to the exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. The solution I found was that you can't put an integer into the `.setText()` (it seems it looks for a id). So all you should have to do in `keystrokeCount.setText(keyCount);` is put a "" before `keyCount`.

Answer (score 1):

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { //per contare i tasti       
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            keycounter++;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }       
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

where keycounter is a field of the activity that contains the EditText.